# arm aarch64 sizeof packed struct is different with 32bit

Tags: c++

I have some code

```
#pragma pack(1) 
typedef struct Data 
{
   unsigned int a;
   unsigned int b;
   unsigned int c;
   char d[16];
  unsigned int f;
}Data;

void f()
{
   Data a;
   memset(&a, 0, sizeof(a));
   a.f =12;
}
```

When I use aarch64_eabi_gcc     aarch64-linux-gnu-g++ tools chain to compile those above code and objdump the object code, I get the following results:

```
 ……
 move x2, #0x24
 mov w1, #0x0
 bl 0<memset>
```

Which means the size of Data is 36bit long instead of 32 bit long, why?
My cpu is arm cortexa53

Comment: Try reordering and placing the `d` member last.  If there is a change, then there was  padding between the `d` and `f` members.

Comment: BTW, in C++, you don't need `typedef struct`.  Use only `struct Data { };`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I have tried reordering member ,same results